# Smallest positive integral value of $a$ such that ${\sin}^2 x+a\cos x+{a}^2>1+\cos x$ holds for all real $x$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, quadratics

> If the inequality $${\sin}^2 x+a\cos x+{a}^2>1+\cos x$$ holds for all $x \in \Bbb R$ then what's the smallest positive integral value of $a$?

Here's my approach to the problem $$\cos^2 x+(1-a)\cos x-a^2<0$$
Let us consider this as a quadratic form respect to $a$.

Applying the quadratic formula $a=\frac{-\cos x\pm\sqrt{5\cos^2 x+4\cos x}}2 $
and substituting $\cos x$ with $1$ and $-1$
we get 3 values of where the graph should touch the x axis $-2,0,1$
How should I proceed now?

Comment: 1. Make a substitution $t = cos(x), t \in[-1, 1]$
 2. Find union of intervals $[\frac{t-\sqrt{5t^2+4t}}{2},\frac{t+\sqrt{5t^2+4t}}{2}]$ where $0 \le 5t^2 + 4t$

Comment: If you could elaborate further please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 
\cos^2{x}+(1-a)\cos{x}-a^2\,\lt0 \quad\&\quad \left|\,\cos{x}\,\right|\,\le1 \\[6mm] 
-1\le\,\cos{x}=\frac12\left(\,-(1-a)\pm\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4a^2}\,\right)\,\le+1 \\ 
-1-a\,\le\,\pm\sqrt{5a^2-2a+1}\,\le\,+3-a \\[6mm] 
\begin{align} 
&\text{For}\,\colon\,\,\,\pm\sqrt{5a^2-2a+1}\,\ge\,-1-a \implies 5a^2-2a+1=a^2+2a+1 \\ 
&\implies 4a^2-4a=a^2-a=0\implies a=0,\,a=1\quad\color{red}{a\in[0,1]} \\[6mm] 
&\text{For}\,\colon\,\,\,\pm\sqrt{5a^2-2a+1}\,\le\,+3-a \implies 5a^2-2a+1=a^2-6a+9 \\ 
&\implies 4a^2+4a-8=a^2+a-2=0\implies a=-2,\,a=1\quad\color{blue}{a\in[-2,1]} \\[6mm] 
\end{align} 
$$ 
Hence, for the inequality $\,\{\cos^2{x}+(1-a)\cos{x}-a^2\,\lt0\}\,$ to hold for all $\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,$ and the operator without equal (less than only), Then: 
$$ \boxed{ \quad \color{blue}{a \in (-\infty,\,-2)\,\wedge\,(1,\infty) } \quad } $$ 
And for $\,a\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\implies\color{red}{a=2}\,$

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The **smallest positive integer** is $1$. That doesn't satisfy the condition, because
$$ \sin^2 x + \cos x + 1 > 1 + \cos x $$
has equality when $\sin^2x = 0$, which happens, among other places, at $x=0$.

The **next positive integer** is $2$. Does that work?
$$ \sin^2 x + 2\cos x + 4 > 1 + \cos x $$
holds if and only if
$$ \sin^2 x + \cos x + 3 > 0 $$
which is easily true -- since $\sin^2 x$ is never less than $0$ and $\cos x$ is never less than $-1$, the left-hand side is always $\ge 2$.

So the answer is $$ \Huge 2 $$

Answer (score 3):

Write *sin$^2$x=1-cos$^2$x*, and factorize the resultant inequation.

Comment: Factorize this expression. I think you should try to figure that by yourself. If you stay stuck for too long, I'll post the solution. Until then, keep at it.

Answer (score 3):

We need that the inequality $\cos^2x+(1-a)\cos{x}-a^2<0$
will be true for all real $x$.

Let $\cos{x}=t$.

Thus, we need to find a smallest natural $a$ for which the inequality 
$$t^2+(1-a)t-a^2<0$$ is true for all $t\in[-1,1],$ for which we need
$$(-1)^2+(1-a)(-1)-a^2<0$$ and
$$1^2+(1-a)\cdot1-a^2<0,$$ which is
$$a^2+a-2>0$$ and $$a^2-a>0,$$ which gives
$$a\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(1,+\infty)$$ and we got the answer: $2$.

Comment: hello sir, sorry for pinging two years late but is there any reason why you did not check for t=1 in particular?